# XPath 1.0: Find all elements that are mentioned inside a different element

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

For example, I have this:

```
<setting>
  <name>text1</name>
</setting>
<setting>
  <name>text2</name>
</setting>
<setting>
  <name>text3</name>
</setting>

<thing>
  <name>name</name>
  <settings>
    <li>text1</li>
    <li>text3</li>
  </settings>
</thing>
```

I need to select all "setting" nodes that are mentioned inside "thing/settings/li".
In the example the xpath should return setting[1] and setting[3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your XML in a single root element so that it is well-formed.  Then...

This XPath,

```
//setting[name=//thing/settings/li]
```

will select all `settings` whose name is among those listed in `//thing/settings/li`:

```
<setting>
  <name>text1</name>
</setting>
<setting>
  <name>text3</name>
</setting>
```

as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this directly with XPath 1.0.
What you can do with XPath 1.0 and some additional code is to get the list of values inside `thing/settings/li` with

```
//thing/settings/li
```

And then to find all the `setting` nodes with those values with something like

```
//setting/name[text()='value']
```

Where `value` will be a parameter passed there form the previously found list.
How to pass the parameter depends on language you are using etc.